# Retrieving data from a database without refreshing the page

Tags: java, database, jstl

I am trying to create a web page that will let the user view the items that are continuously sent by an another web page.

Here is the sample code for viewing the items:

```
<h1>View Order</h1>

    <sql:setDataSource dataSource="jdbc/conn"/>
    <sql:query var="results" sql="SELECT item from orders"/>

    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${results.rowCount == 0}">
            <p class="info">There are no items.</p>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:set var="count" value="0" scope="page" />
            <c:forEach var="result" items="${results.rows}">
                 <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page"/>
                <div class="order">
                   <h1>Order number ${count}</h1> <span>${result.item}</span>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

Is it possible to make it retrieve data without refreshing the page? Suggestions and advices please. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but you must use JavaScript and AJAX. Once the page is sent to the browser, your server cannot modify it on its own. The browser itself must fetch the new data from the server and update the page accordingly, and that's where AJAX and JavaScript come into play.

Note that if you are going to use standard AJAX, you're probably going to need to poll the server at regular intervals just to ask if anything has changed.

There are ways to push messages from the server to the browser directly, but you'll need to use more complicated technologies such as CometD or Atmosphere.